# How draw a dot on canvas on click event Tkinter Python

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have the following piece of code that takes an image within a canvas and then whenever I click the paint function draws a dot over it.

Everything is working fine **except** that the paint function is not working as expected.

**Desirable output**

Click event draws a dot. No need to drag the on click event

**Actual output**

I have to drag the on mouse click event to see a drawing on the canvas.

I guess there might be a slight problem with the paint function. However, I haven't been able to know what it is exactly.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Main(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = None

    def main(self):
        master = Tk()

        # Right side of the screen / image holder
        right_frame = Frame(master, width=500, height=500, cursor="dot")
        right_frame.pack(side=LEFT)

        # Retrieve image
        image = Image.open("./image/demo.JPG")
        image = image.resize((800, 700), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

        # Create canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(right_frame, width=800, height=700)
        self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.paint)

        mainloop()

    def paint(self, event):
        python_green = "#476042"
        x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
        x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
        self.canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill=python_green, outline=python_green, width=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().main()
```

Fix:

Added these two methods:

```
def on_button_press(self, event):
    self.x = event.x
    self.y = event.y

def on_button_release(self, event):
    python_green = "#476042"
    x0,y0 = (self.x, self.y)
    x1,y1 = (event.x, event.y)
```

changed canvas to this:

```
self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you only click and don't move the mouse, `B1-Motion` isn't triggering.

To bind to mouse press (as well as mouse moving), you can add `self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.paint)` before the `mainloop`.